# On-the-go cloud file encryption (end-to-end)

Tags: gratis, encryption, cloud-service

So I'm looking for some software which will encrypt my files *before* they are sent into the realms of the cloud (Google Drive).  The crucial aspect is that I must be able to access my files from my iOS devices whenever I'm on the go.

Summary of requirements:

- Needs to be compatible with Google Drive
- Needs to allow me to access my files in the cloud from my iOS devices
- Windows and Mac OSX compatible
- Price is **free**
- Allows in-app access of files from Office for iOS apps

Desirable (i.e. not essential) attributes:

- Can sync encryption keys via USB rather than an online account